# Replace in all tables in db file

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm not sure if something like this is possible, but I have a db file with multiple tables in it. In some of those tables there are guids that are used as references across the tables. Is there anyway I can basically do a search and replace of a value in all the tables? (One thing that make make this easier is that the column has the same name in every table). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can open the .sqlite or .db file in any of the editors and do find and replace.
2. You can import the DB file in database and add property called ON UPDATE CASCADE and then perform update on the parent table.
3. You can write a script to update that particular element.